# Sniffing outside network dit Python

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

I need to sniff a server for get http packet which is outside of my network for a project.
For the moment, I have only sniffing in my network or when I am connected to this server... I have tried with scapy and socket.

Do you know how to do ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about/looking for is [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)

Promiscuous mode allows frames that are not addressed to a node to be passed up to the kernel for processing

```
ip link set $IFACE promisc on
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't works... if I use tcpdump or tshark, normally, I can see this packets with this mode ?